# Is there any way to override @AuthenticationPrincipal in spring boot app?

Tags: spring-security

I need to implement communication among micro services (requests that are already authenticated). I am going to pass userId in request headers. These userId I want to be accessible by @AuthenticationPrincipal annotation, like that:

```
public ResponseEntity somemethod(@AuthenticationPrincipal Long userId)
{
....
}
```

Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

The `@AuthenticationPrincipal` annotation is really a shorthand for:

```java
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal()
```

You can set the same with a custom filter with code like:

```java
Authentication authentication = new PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken(userId, null);
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
```